# ActionListener not working on JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I have written a code to display three buttons in three panels on a 
frame with grid layout. 
The objective is to
 - change color of button when the button is clicked
 - initially all 3 of them are black

The code runs perfectly except for the color of button doesn't change on
click.
Can anyone please point out the problem or debug it.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class gui extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JPanel p1, p2, p3;
    JButton b1, b2, b3;

    public gui() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        JPanel p3 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        JButton b1 = new JButton();
        JButton b2 = new JButton();
        JButton b3 = new JButton();
        b1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        b2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        b3.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        b1.addActionListener(this);
        p1.add(b1);
        b2.addActionListener(this);
        p2.add(b2);
        b3.addActionListener(this);
        p3.add(b3);
        add(p1);
        add(p2);
        add(p3);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) //function to handle click
    {
        if (e.getSource() == b1) {
            b1.setBackground(Color.RED);
        } else if (e.getSource() == b2) {
            b1.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        } else if (e.getSource() == b3) {
            b3.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        gui ob1 = new gui();
        ob1.setSize(1000, 500);
        ob1.setLocation(100, 100);
        ob1.setVisible(true);
        ob1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a typo I think. Change `b1.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);` to `b2.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);` in the second `if`...

Comment: got it you rediclared the buttons and pannel they are nullglobally.huhu got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to initialize the buttons using[Same applied to panels as well]

   ```
    b1 = new JButton();
    b2 = new JButton();
    b3 = new JButton();
   ```

   because you are creating local variables which hides the global variables

   ```
   JButton b1 = new JButton();//local variables
   JButton b2 = new JButton();
   JButton b3 = new JButton();
   ```
2. In the second if condition you have to change the color of b2 not b1

   ```
        else if(e.getSource()==b2){

               //b1.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
               b2.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

               }
   ```
3. Always use `.equals()` instead of `==` to compare objects

   ```
      e.getSource().equals(b1)
   ```